# Format a tumblr JSON date?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to display content from my Tumblr blog on my own website for some time. After a bit of searching I've managed to embed:

- The Headline
- Make the headline a link
- The date

I followed the JSON instructions on this website ([janzheng.com](http://janzheng.com/2013/06/tumblr_integration.html)) It works really well, the only problem is the date format isn't how I'd like to display it.

The date is output as: Fri, 26 Sep 2014 10:01:51

I'd like to display it as: **26/09/2014**

*Can anyone who's familiar with JSON offer some guidance?*

**This is the script that outputs the date:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">document.write('<p class="date">' + tumblr_api_read['posts'][0]['date'] + '</p>');</script>
```

Comment: As the answers below mention, you need to convert the date yourself. The API will not take care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing that code with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theDate = new Date(tumblr_api_read['posts'][0]['date']);
var day = theDate.getDay();
var month = theDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = theDate.getFullYear();
var newDate = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
document.write('<p class="date">' + newDate + '</p>');
</script>
```

I've not worked with tumbler and can't test it, but it should do the trick. Otherwise let me know what it outputs and I can ammend it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look at this for me - much appreciated. It works, but the date is wrong? It outputs the date as the 5th when I know it was the 26th?

Answer (score 1):

Some people don't like using a lot of external libraries, but I like using MomentJS http://momentjs.com/ for formatting dates. It might be a little overkill here, but they make things really easy.

Comment: Hi Jan, looks good. Any chance you could explain how to use the Tumblr code with MomentJS?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `toLocaleDateString` with `en-GB` as locale (for `dd/mm/yyyy`).

`var date = 'Fri, 26 Sep 2014 10:01:51'; // Your tumblr date
(new Date(date)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')`

Currently only [IE 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility) - so depends on your needs.

Alternatively you could let the users browser determine the format and leave out the locale (`en-GB`) - then you should be good to go in most browsers (including mobile - see link above).